# Looking for Simple C Implementation of AES-128 and DES

Tags: c, aes, implementation, des, sparc

I need C versions of AES-128 and DES to run on an embedded SPARC processor. I'm trying to measure the electrical power of these algorithms in software and hardware. Is there a website where I could find software implementations? Currently I can compile C code with my cross-compiler so any language implementations other than C would not be useful.

I have implemented DES in hardware before. How much work would people estimate (hours/lines of code) to implement a software version?

Does anybody know how to use the aes_generic.c and des_generic.c built into the Linux kernel in the crypto directory?

Comment: When you say "the power of these algorithms", are you talking about cryptographic strength? If so you should know DES is by no means safe for modern use; it is interesting only in a historical context.

Comment: I guess that is ambiguous. I meant the electrical power consumption.

Comment: I used OpenSsl library, it is good library.

Comment: If you're doing embedded cryptography you should be aware of [power analysis](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=power+analysis+attacks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to see if [LibTomCrypt](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt) will meet your needs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I checked it out and it seems too complicated.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, but learning curve was higher than I wanted. It took me about 1-2 hours to figure out how to use the library and probably a couple more hours to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of [AES implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations).  Simple googling also found a [DES](http://www.ubiqx.org/proj/libcifs/source/Auth/DES.c) implementation in C; you'll have to see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: That DES isn't complete, but I'll see if I can use it.